# Document set welcome page image

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, document-set

I have created document set in my document library like Finance, IT, Consulting,  Marketing, HR and etc.

I want **different images for differenet document set item**.so is it possible to set images for each document set item ?

[image: Document Set image]

I want different images for each document set item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.  The webpart that displays that image is just a static link to an image, so the only way that could change is if you created several distinct document set content types and changed the image for each content type.

So, you'd have a Finance Docset content type with one welcome page image, an HR docset content type with another.

Comment: can i use different images in single doc set content type

Comment: You'd have to either manually or programmatically change them, but sure.  If you're asking if there's a way for a single document set content type to use a different image in that webpart based on some metadata selection, no, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a separate image for particular document set because the same aspx page is reused for each item. So any web parts you add to the page will be the same for all instances/items of the same document set (aka content type).

But you can create a new column on the document set content type of type "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" and call it say "Image Thumbnail". Then you can edit the document set from the document library (via "document set settings"), and then add the "Image Thumbnail" column as the last column in "welcome page columns". Do not make it a "shared column" unless you want every item to have the image on it, which is totally unnecessary if all you want is to display a unique image for each item on the document set page.

You would then have a generic image of the left hand side of the document set web page but a unique image for each item would display as the last column in the in the "welcome page columns". Looks quite good.