# Document Set welcome page image - customise image per item

Tags: content-type, document-set, connected-web-parts, image-display, welcome-page

I would like to display the photo for Employee X in their individual document set, when their document set is opened (display form / aka Document Set Welcome Page).

When I look at the document set for Employee Y, I would like Employee Y's photo to display on the page.

Currently I have managed to change the default image, but it is static.  I can not find a way of getting individual employee photos to load up.

Currently I have this on the Document Set Welcome Page:
[image: Document Set Welcome Page]

I'd like to have this on the Document Set Welcome Page - photo automatically loads, by filtering on either `Employee Name field` or `Employee Photo ID field` or something.
[image: Doc Set Welcome Page with Photo]

The `employee photos` are stored in a list in the same site collection, so it should be quite straightforward to connect them.

**Research:** [Referenced link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145641/document-set-welcome-page-image).  It is stated that it is not possible to achieve what I need.  Though perhaps inserting a different web part to replace the default 'Image' web part could enable this to work?

Link [How to use the thumbnail (_t) photo](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2225267/microsoft-subnet/sharepoint-trick--link-to-an-image-thumbnail.html)

[This link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97425/how-do-i-add-web-parts-to-a-document-sets-welcome-page-that-depend-on-metadata) appears to be similar to what I want to achieve, although I only have one photo per employee, rather than a collection of photos.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a separate image for particular document set because the same aspx page is reused for each item. So any web parts you add to the page will be the same for all instances/items of the same document set (aka content type).

But you can create a new column on the document set content type of type "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" and call it say "Image Thumbnail". Then you can edit the document set from the document library (via "document set settings"), and then add the "Image Thumbnail" column as the last column in "welcome page columns". Do not make it a "shared column" unless you want every item to have the image on it, which is totally unnecessary if all you want is to display a unique image for each item on the document set page.

You would then have a generic image of the left hand side of the document set web page but a unique image for each item would display as the last column in the in the "welcome page columns". Looks quite good.